# Do you get a gold when playing Trading Post?

Tags: 7-wonders

The symbols for Trading Post show a one gold symbol above the symbols for the resources.  Does this indicate that playing the card gives you a gold (in addition to getting a discount from it), or is it just supposed to remind you that you now only have to pay one gold for the resources shown?  We've always played that you get a gold for playing it, but the rules don't seem conclusive either way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you do not receive any coins. It is indicating a discount. You only pay {1} Coin instead of the normal {2} from the neighbor in the direction to which the arrow points. You can contrast this with the **Tavern** card.

[7-Wonder's rule book](http://www.rprod.com/files/7W_RULES_EN_COLOR_LIGHT.pdf) (page 12).

> **Tavern Icon** - the card is worth the amount of coins pictured, the coins are taken from the bank only once, when the card is played.
>
> **Trading Post Icon** - starting on the turn following the one in which this building was constructed, the player purchases raw materials from the neighboring city indicated by the arrow for 1 coin instead of 2.
>
> Clarification for the Eastern Trading Post, the Western Trading Post and the Marketplace: arrows show to which neighboring city or cities to which the discount applies.

[image: 7-Wonders Trading Post]

Comment: We always looked at that and thought that since the 1 resembled the 5, and it says "the amount of coins pictured" (implying that it could be something other than 5) that it applied to both cards.  Guess that isn't the case.

Comment: It took me WAY too long to realize that this question (and answer, obviously) is about *7 Wonders*, and **not** Dominion!

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't receive any money for playing Trading Post.  It's just a reminder that one gold is your new cost for resources purchased from your neighbors.